# Connection to 1433 port not working from outside, while port is redirected from router

Tags: sql-server, port

I am trying to open access to my SQL Server from outside my network, but while my ports are open in my Windows Firewall and routed from my router, telnet can't connect.

To explain a bit more I have opened both TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 ports in my Windows Firewall to allow remote access to my SQL Server.
Ports seems to be properly opened in my windows firewall as both a telnet [local_server_ip]  1433 and SSMS can connect from a different computer within my local network.

When trying to connect from outside my network (using my external IP) Telnet can't connect (Connect failed).
In my router, ports are redirected (TCP 1433 and UDP 1434) and I also tried setting my SQL Server IP as DMZ but it did not went through. My other port redirection works properly so I don't think it comes from the router (for instance I have Emby as a media server, and I can access it from outside my network or use telnet to connect to the port opened for this service).

Am I missing a configuration in SQL Server configuration manager? For instance I had to manually set the TCP port in SQL Server Network Configuration > TCP/IP properties > IP Adresses > IPAll and set TCP Port as 1433
Or can it come from either my Windows Firewall (even though the inbound rules has similar characteristics as the inbound rule for my Emby server) or my router?

Answer (score 0):

So locally it all seems to work, but from outside it does not?  This does indicate your router NAT setting being an issue.

Just to point out, exposing an SQL Server to public internet is relatively insecure. Ideally you add a VPN to your local network and use that to reach the SQL server instead. Just to point out, I can imagine it could work, but you might want to rethink the setup.

Comment: I'll check again the router, maybe I'll figure out why some port redirection works and other don't.
I am curious though on the security concerns. Why would allowing an outside connection to my sql server be more insecure than allowing an outside connection to my Emby server ?